# negative lookbefore for a blackslash in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, negative-lookbehind

I want to match every '[' or ']' that's not preceded by a backslash in ruby 1.9
I tried:

```
/?<!\134[\[\]]/
```

and

```
/?<!\\\\[\[\]]/
```

but I get a 'target of repeat operator not specified'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the negative lookbehind in parenthesis.

```
(?<!\\)[\[\]]
```